# CSS Minimizer error when building react js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I got the following error after updating react-scripts.

static/css/main.57ddad44.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.

The confusing part for me is that npm start is working but npm run build is not. I read some of the solutions to these problems and they all had the problem with CSS, but in my case I couldn't find the problem with css.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: did you get the solution?? It is happening in Angular as well.

Comment: How were you able to fix it

Comment: Any update on this please, I am also facing the same issue in my reactjs application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go over your css files, usually this caused by the bad commenting in css file.

Usual commenting is like /* some comment */, but in some case, you might have some bad commenting like **/ or etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue occured because of the optimization regarding relative paths that refer to css files in my js files. So adding this code in my webpack config file solved the problem :

```
optimization: {
    portableRecords: true,
  },
```

see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/